# Kivy Buildozer Apk - Import Custom Modules

Tags: android, module, kivy, buildozer

On Windows Plat, I extend the python path to include my module folder.  That works fine but once the kivy program is compiled by Buildozer into an apk,

the 'import' command no longer loads my modules.  The log file reads....

> [WARNING] stderr: ImportError: No module named a_sync

Errors on first module.

Is there some special way to import your own modules from the folder you set up in your database directory?

-------update-------------

I don't think my apk will import the pyo files.  I can see where I extended the python path to my modules...but no import.

----update----------
The apk runs now but the graphics aren't right.  Kivy Launcher runs the app perfectly (graphics and all), so what could possible be going wrong with the buildozer build?

The visuals have this funny looking distortion.  Example, if a png image is round like a circle, kivy apk running shows the same graphic like a star or flower (not fully round anymore).

---update----
I updated the Kivy Launcher and it too has the distorted graphcis rendering.

Comment: I have to create a detailed tutorial on how to setup the virtual guess on windows all the way to building with buildozer because there's a lot of little ins-and-outs you just can't find anywhere on the net.  I managed to get my app running....finally...it only took over a week.  Something else is wrong though...my graphics are all messed up.  The Kivy Launcher ran my app perfectly, graphics and all...so what goes wrong when using buildozer to create the apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dropped custom modules in the same place main.py (pyo) is located.  Kivy is like another API set I used in the past except kivy is not a full fledge 3D engine.  Like the 3D engine I used in the past, final packages ran from a virtual environment.  The difference then was the fact I could store my custom modules in python's site-packages directory.

With that not being the case in kivy (at least not through buildozer), root directory is best opt.

Answer (score 0):

P4A has set the path automatically and you most likely can't modify it other way than this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('your path')
```

Comment: I got my modules to work by dumping them in the root folder but I can't do this with my resources that are in my cab folder which holds the graphics.  The moment my app tried to load a wav file that did exits, the app closed with the "no such file for directory" error.  Why can't the app see it's own root folder that holds the main.pyo?  If you can't have a database folder...then there's nothing much you can do with kivy.

Comment: Please read python's documentation of how `import` works. If you can't load a file, use `os` module, to find it e.g. `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` is a root dir if such functions are run in `main.py`. I don't have a clue what is that "database" folder. If it's Java thing, it's not related to Kivy even a tiny bit. Dumping whole framework because you can't load a file and most likely you haven't seen python docs related to such topic at all is just stupid.

Comment: I know how the import goes, been using python for years.  My module problem turned out to be a spec file issue.  Kivy docs do not cover little small "ins-and-outs" so a user could possible slip up on those issues, like I did.  In the future,  I want to write a complete, detailed doc on the virtual machine, kivy and buildozer...including those unmentioned things that pinned me to the ground.