# ModuleNotFoundError through Kivy's buildozer into APK?

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'm new to python and very new to Kivy and created a simple app that converts a Youtube video to MP3 using the youtube_dl module. However, the app keeps crashing after showing the Kivy loading screen. Through the logcat, this error was displayed:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'youtube_dl'
Python for android ended.
```

What can I do to download the module directly to the android apk? Or are there other solutions? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to drop the module named `youtube_dl` into your main folder contain your main python file.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777193/kivy-buildozer-apk-import-custom-modules)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the youtube-dl module on my laptop and the app works perfectly fine on the desktop, just not when it's converted to APK using Kivy's buildozer. Is there anyway to put this module into the app on android? Sorry if it's a very stupid question, i'm very new.